# Почему код в Unity действует на объекты по разному?

Tags: unity3d, blender

Есть 2 объекта сделанные в блендере и импортированные в Unity.

**Eye of the Cyclops.blend**
[image]

**Flask.blend**:
[image]

Проблема состоит в том, что после использования кода, который должен создавать предмет в области рук-тела(я над этим ещё работаю) один предмет создаётся далеко от персонажа.

***Пример:***
Всё окей.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не окей.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

***Код:***
***PlayerInteraction:***

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerInteraction : MonoBehaviour
{

    public GameObject target = null;

    public KeyCode interactKey;

    public GameObject itemHolder;

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(interactKey))
        {
            if (target == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            FoodBox food = target.GetComponent<FoodBox>();
            if (food != null && itemHolder == null)
            {
                food.Interact(this);
            }

            TableBox table = target.GetComponent<TableBox>();
            if (table != null)
            {
                table.Interact(itemHolder, this);
            }

        }
    }

    public void SetItem(GameObject c)
    {
        if (c != null)
        {
            Debug.Log("Взяли предмет!");
            itemHolder = Instantiate(c, transform.position + new Vector3(0f, 2.15f, -0.65f), Quaternion.Euler(-90f, 0f, 180f), transform);
        }
        else
        {
            Destroy(itemHolder);
        }
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col)
    {
        if (target != col.gameObject && target != null)
        {
            return;
        }
        else {
            target = col.gameObject;
            Debug.Log("Мы дошли сюда до " + target.name);
        }

    }

    private void OnTriggerExit(Collider col)
    {
        if (col.gameObject == target)
        {
            target = null;
        }
    }
}
```

***TableBox:***

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class TableBox : MonoBehaviour
{

    public GameObject itemHolder;

    private void Start()
    {
        if (itemHolder != null)
        {
            itemHolder = Instantiate(itemHolder, transform.position + new Vector3(0f, 1.9f, 0f), Quaternion.Euler(-90f, 45f, 0f),transform);
            Debug.Log("Мы создались!!");
        }
    }

    public void Interact(GameObject i, PlayerInteraction player)
    {
        if ((i == null || itemHolder == null))
        {
            player.SetItem(this.itemHolder);
            Destroy(this.itemHolder);
            //Debug.Log(itemHolder);
            this.itemHolder = i;

            if (this.itemHolder != null)
            {
                this.itemHolder = Instantiate(this.itemHolder, transform.position + new Vector3(0f, 1.9f, 0f), Quaternion.Euler(-90f, 0f, -135f),transform);
                Debug.Log("Мы ингридиенты из ТейблБокса!");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

***FoodBox:***

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class FoodBox : MonoBehaviour
{

    public GameObject ingredient;
    private Animator anim;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
        anim.SetBool("openFoodBox",false);
    }
    public void Interact(PlayerInteraction player)
    {
        anim.SetBool("openFoodBox", true);

        if (anim.GetBool("openFoodBox")) {
            anim.Play("Opening");
            player.SetItem(ingredient);
            Debug.Log("Мы ингридиенты из ФудБокса!");
        }

        anim.SetBool("openFoodBox",false);
    }
}
```

Есть также предположение, что это из-за изначального положения моделей. Потому что у меня некоторые модели сохраняются нормально вертикально, а некоторые ложатся горизонтально.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Добавляю также инспектор префабов:

Eye of the Cyclops:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Flask:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: все что замоделено должно иметь одинаковую ориентацию, положение и масштаб

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Ответ дан с ветки [Game Development](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/173484/76308) и приведён ниже.*

Как обычно, ответ на вопрос «Почему Unity делает эту причудливую вещь?» звучит так: «Unity делает совершенно нормальную вещь с причудливыми данными, которые вы ей дали»

В этом случае начало координат ваших колб в Blender находится далеко за пределами самого объекта, где синие и красные стрелки пересекаются на изображении ниже:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это точка, которая становится локальной (0, 0, 0) точкой при импорте меша в Unity.

Чтобы объект находился там, где вы хотели, вам нужно было добавить существенное вертикальное смещение к позиции вашего объекта (+ new Vector3 (0f, 1.9f, 0f) в вашем коде), чтобы поместить этот источник высоко над вашим персонажем, чтобы видимый меш под ней выстроится там, где вы хотели.

Но когда вы создаёте объект с началом координат в более ожидаемой позиции всё по другому - начало координат вашего объекта ***Eye of Cyclop*** находится в его центре - в результате видимый меш сидит выше, чем вы хотите.

Таким образом, лучшее решение - это моделировать ваши объекты с началом координат в стандартизированном месте относительно видимого меша (скажем, вокруг его центра массы или у его основания). [Посмотрите, как изменить начало координат объекта в Blender здесь](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1291/change-pivot-or-local-origin-of-an-object).

Если по какой-либо причине исправить исходный меш не представляется возможным, вы также можете обернуть его в пустой родительский игровой объект и перемещать дочерний меш до тех пор, пока он не окажется в нужном вам месте относительно источника родителя. Затем создайте и управляйте родителем, а не мешем напрямую.